# Bold cite keys in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, biblatex-phys

I am currently using biblatex (biber backend) with `style=phys`. In my bibliography, I have a few "highlighted publications" that I am setting in bold, using

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{highlight}
\AtEveryBibitem{\ifcategory{highlight}{\bfseries}{}}
\addtocategory{highlight}{myWork1,myWork2}
```

which works like a charm.
Now I would like the cite labels of the highlight category to show up in bold (and perhaps a different color), both in the bibliography as well as (even more important) in the main text. I have tried `\AtEveryCite{\ifcategory{highlight}{\bfseries}{}}` but that did not work at all.

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

EDIT: Please see below for my MWE

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
    author={A. Uthor},
    title = {A neat paper},
    journal = {Some random Journal},
    year = {2013}
}

@article{highlightEntry,
    author={Me},
    title = {Something great},
    journal = {Some Journal},
    year = {2023}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

%%% packages %%%
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbib,nottoc]{tocbibind} %%% bibsection style
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

%%% bibliography stuff %%%

\usepackage[style=phys,biblabel=brackets,backend=biber,pageranges=false,defernumbers=true,maxnames=8]{biblatex}


\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{#1}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\small}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.1\baselineskip}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{higlight}
\AtEveryBibitem{\ifcategory{higlight}{\bfseries}{}}

% highlighted papers
\addtocategory{higlight}{highlightEntry}

%%% bibliography style settings %%%
\let\OLDthebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand\thebibliography[1]{
  \OLDthebibliography{#1}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%{0.5ex plus 0.1ex}
}


\begin{document}

\section{My text}

test reference \cite{test} and then this second cite-key should be in bold \cite{highlightEntry}

\section{My bib}

\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code (do not forget to add two or three bib entries too) , then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Hi @Mensch, thank you! I have added a MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\AtEveryCitekey` and not `\AtEveryCite`.

The latter is appended to whenever you issue a citation command, and the manual specifically says:

> No bibliographic data is available at this point.

The former is appended at the beginning of processing for each cite key in a citation command, and the bibliographic data is available for it.

---

Complete example:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
    author={A. Uthor},
    title = {A neat paper},
    journal = {Some random Journal},
    year = {2013}
}

@article{highlightEntry,
    author={Me},
    title = {Something great},
    journal = {Some Journal},
    year = {2023}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

%%% packages %%%
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbib,nottoc]{tocbibind} %%% bibsection style
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

%%% bibliography stuff %%%

\usepackage[style=phys,biblabel=brackets,backend=biber,pageranges=false,defernumbers=true,maxnames=8]{biblatex}


\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{#1}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\small}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.1\baselineskip}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{higlight}
\AtEveryBibitem{\ifcategory{higlight}{\bfseries}{}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\ifcategory{higlight}{\bfseries}{}} % Sets citation key, so prints bold when in category
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\ifcategory{higlight}{\bfseries}{}#1} % Make bibliography label also bold if in category

% highlighted papers
\addtocategory{higlight}{highlightEntry}

%%% bibliography style settings %%%
\let\OLDthebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand\thebibliography[1]{
  \OLDthebibliography{#1}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%{0.5ex plus 0.1ex}
}


\begin{document}

\section{My text}

test reference \cite{test} and then this second cite-key should be in bold \cite{highlightEntry}

\section{My bib}

\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Willie Wong, thank you, that works! But unfortanetly the numeric label in the bibliography is not made bold using that command, do you have any suggestion for fixing this? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that part of your question. You need to also modify how the `labelnumber` field is printed in the bibliography. Let me add a complete example (should be done in about 5 minutes).